# Quick Question Integration with Joint PDF

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ by independent and identically distributed random variables with probability density function (pdf)
>   $$f_X(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}1, & 0 < x < 1\\ 0, & \text{otherwise.}\end{array}\right.$$
>
> 1. Show that the joint pdf of $X_{(1)} = \min\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\}$ and $X_{(n)} = \max\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\}$ is
>      $$f_{X_{(1)},X_{(n)}}(x, y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}n(n-1)(y-x)^{n-2}, & 0 < x < y < 1\\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$
> 2. Let $R = X_{(n)} - X_{(1)}$ be the range of the random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$.
>      By using the formula
>      $$
>    P(R \le u) = \iint\limits_{y \le x + u} f_{X_{(1)},X_{(n)}}(x, y)\, dy\, dx,
>    $$
>      show that $P(R \le u) = n(1 - u)u^{n-1} + u^n$, $0 < u < 1$.

For part 2, what are the upper and lower limits of $Y$ and $X$?

I tried $x$ from $0$ to $u$ and $y$ from $0$ to $x + u$. And this doesn't work.

Please help. Could you please help me out if you see this please ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please [edit] your question to include your thoughts on this problem, explaining what you've tried and what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I've edited my question could you please help me with this question? All I need are 2 sets of limits :)

Comment: @user156422 It probably doesn't work because $f(x, y)$ is defined over $0 < x < y < 1$ and *not* over $0 < y < x < 1$. So you should have $x < y < x + u$ (with $u < 1$, of course).

Comment: In such problems, it helps to make sketch the region involved and work things out on it, seeing to it that your integration doesn't go outside the boundaries.

Comment: Is x from 0 to u ?

Comment: I understand y limits but the x limits sem a problem could you please help? I've drawn the graph but not sure it's correct.

Comment: No, $x$ should be from $0$ to $1$ (in the outer integral).

Comment: I checked that doesnt work

Comment: Oh yes, I'm very sorry, there is a problem with that. If you sketch the region, you'll see that the line $y = x + u$ (for some arbitrary $u$ between $0$ and $1$) intersects the upper boundary $y = 1$, at $x = 1 - u$. So the integral has to be split. In one, $0 < x < 1 - u$ and $x < y < x + u$, and in the other, $1 - u < x < 1$ and $x < y < 1$. The integrand is the same in both, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, let $g(x, y) = f_{X_{(1)}, X_{(n)}}(x, y)$. The region is:

[image: Region of integration]

\begin{align}
P(R \le u) & = \iint\limits_{y \le x + u}g(x, y)\, dy\, dx\\
& = \int\limits_0^{1-u} \int\limits_x^{x+u} n(n−1)(y−x)^{n−2}\, dy\, dx +
 \int\limits_{1-u}^1 \int\limits_x^1 n(n−1)(y−x)^{n−2}\, dy\, dx\\
& = n(1 - u)u^{n - 1} + u^n,\ 0 < u < 1
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! That explains it :) Last question: if you differentiate it to get the pdf, does it match any known distribution ? I diffreentiated it but the answer was like n(n-1)u^(n-2)-n^2u^(n-1)+nu^(n-1)

Comment: And that doesn't look like anything...

Comment: That is $n(n - 1)(1 - u)u^{n - 2}$, $0 < u < 1$, but I can't find any standard distribution like it.

Comment: is it beta? but then you need to sort of manipulate the factorial components

Comment: Oh, of course you're right! For the beta distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the pdf can be written as $\dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}x^{\alpha - 1}(1 - x)^{\beta - 1}$. Then if you take $\alpha = n - 1$ and $\beta = 2$, you get $\dfrac{\Gamma(n + 1)}{\Gamma(n - 1)\Gamma(2)}x^{n - 2}(1 - x)$, and $\Gamma(n + 1) = n(n-1)\Gamma(n - 1)$, and all that unwanted stuff cancels out neatly!